# Are Pull Down Resistors too Slow to read Encoder Counts?

Tags: resistors, encoder, pulldown

I'm planning on using the LPC1768's QEI module for reading a motor's encoder (which has a high resolution - http://encoder.com/literature/datasheet-770.pdf).

I've read some people have hooked up their encoders to the module using pull down resistors [https://os.mbed.com/users/hexley/notebook/qei_hw-interface-implementation-notes/, however, apparently this is only suitable for reading panel encoders turned by humans because the pull down is too slow for high-speed application.

If this is the case, what would be an alternative to using a pull down/up resistor?

Ultimately I'd like to know the best way to hook up an encoder without losing counts.

Comment: Ah the standard resistor that only comes with one value.

Comment: Link to datasheet? (Put it in the question - not in the comments.)

Comment: See update... :)

Comment: Should work now - the square bracket found its way into the link.

Comment: We need the datasheet of the encoder, not the schematic. I know how an encoder connects to a CPU.

Comment: I haven't picked one yet, but it will operate on 5V, and provide 2048PPR.

Comment: So you want us to provide a solution for a problem you don't know yet **if** it will exist, not having any idea what it connects to. (Also you have not provided RPM which sets the frequency of the signals). I vote to close this.

Comment: I'll mostly end up using https://www.ato.com/incremental-rotary-encoder-hollow-shaft-2048-ppr
I have one of these lying around.

Comment: So, what part of "we need the datasheet" don't you understand? Or do you think that you actually linked to one?

Comment: I don't have one, but if you scroll down most of the specs are there.

Comment: Could you please be specific about what it is exactly you need to know?

Comment: I've added the datasheet for another encoder I own.

Comment: Many high-resolution/high-rate encoders are going to have active circuitry that drives in both directions.  Pulling resistors are more something you'd find with mechanical switch encoders or low resolution *discrete* phototransistors, rather than the kind of sensor heads used in high resolution encoders.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, thanks. Could you elaborate on what you mean by active circuitry? With a 5v encoder, could I connect this directly to the CPU, without resistors, etc?

Comment: As everyone's been telling you, **read the data sheet**.  If you have a push/pull or otherwise bidirectional driver of *appropriate signaling voltage* and the environment is electrically quiet and the lead lengths are short enough to preclude worry about transmission line effect, potentially yes.  Some of these things may not be true in common machinery installation environments.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, When you say "drives in both directions", do you mean the MCU sinks or sources, depending on whether the output is high or low?

Comment: That questions doesn't make any sense - it's the encoder that drives, not the MCU.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, sorry that's what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do is to figure what the fastest toggling speed of any of the lines will be.  Find the fastest shaft speed you need to handle, then figure out the toggle frequency out of the encoder for that.

Once you know the fastest response time you need, this problem no longer has anything to do with a encoder.  It's really about how stiff a pullup or pulldown needs to be to float the line to the released state when it is no longer actively driven to the opposite state.  This is mostly a RC time constant calculation.

Let's say you decide that there will be no more than 100 pF of parasitic capacitance on a line, and that the fastest toggle rate is 10 kHz.  Each cycle is 100 µs long, so each level is 50 µs long.  If you need to decode two of these lines in quadrature, one should be well settled before the other starts to change.  Let's say you therefore decide you want each line to settle to 90% within 10 µs.

90% settling happens in 2.3 time constants.  One time constant is therefore (10 µs)/2.3 = 4.35 µs.  The minimum pullup or pulldown resistance is therefore (4.35 µs)/(100 pF) = 43.5 kΩ.  That's actually rather high.  Unless this is a particularly low power application where you need to conserve 10s of µA, I'd just use 10 kΩ in this case.

Note that most of these devices have open drain or open collector outputs with a common ground.  You would therefore need pullup, not pulldown, resistors.  Check the datasheet to make sure you are using the correct polarity.  High speed devices usually drive both ways and don't need pullups/pulldowns at all.  Again, check the datasheet.

Comment: So the encoder I'm using has an optional TTL output. So I'm assuming I don't need a pull up/down at all?

Comment: @M-R: A true TTL output needs no pullup or pulldown if it is driving something TTL-compatible.

Comment: I imagine most MCUs such as the LPC1768 are TTL compatible? What do you mean by a true TTL output?

Comment: @M-R: Don't imagine, read the datasheet.  Check the guaranteed high and low levels of the output, and compare that to the minimum required high and low levels of the input.

Comment: The datasheet for this encoder isn't entirely clear on the guaranteed output levels. It only mentions that a Differential Line Driver Output can be chosen. Am I to assume that makes it TTL-compatible? https://ecatalog.dynapar.com/downloads/E23_DS_701949_2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If there is quite a big distance (more than a foot) you really should use a voltage at least 1/2 way in its operational range. Because, over time, the photo transistors are going to lose gain. As far as counter accuracy, you will want to use the balanced signal lines (they call it differential or push-pull) into an op-amp that you level shift back to TTL. Because it will have the best noise immunity (about 40 dB over the open collector or unbalanced configuration).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the push-pull output, then you don't need pull-up or pull-down resistors, except maybe to establish a known state with the encoder disconnected. That's because the push-pull outputs should be able to drive tens of mA and easily switch at such a relatively low frequency (200kHz max).

Using open-collector or drain outputs, the time constant will be R*C where C is the sum of the cable capacitance and input capacitance. If you want it to work at 200kHz, the time on and off is 1/400,000 second or 2.5usec. If you allow four time constants (two time constants in quadrature) then you'll want the time constant to be less than 630nsec. With a resistor of 2.2K you'd have to have capacitance less than 280pF. If your cable is 40pF/foot that's about 7' of cable. You can go as low as 1/10 of that (20mA, assuming the logic levels hold) and that means 10x the cable length, all other things being equal.

So I don't think you will have a problem on that account unless you try to do something silly like using 100K or 10K resistors with a cable.

The QEI interface, being hardware, should easily respond at 200kHz but you may have insufficient resolution to read the velocity accurately, check the datasheet.